# python: using Sets and .intersection on a file of twitter followers & friends ids

Tags: python, set, intersection

I have a Couch DB with followers and friends ids of a single twitter user. Friends are identified under the group “friend_edges” and followers under “follower_edges”.

I am trying to find ids of those who are both followers and friends (at the same time) of that user.

In order to do that, I was requested to convert lists of followers and friends into sets, and then use the intersection operation between sets-- like set1.intersection(set.2)

Below is my code. It returns the only 2 values of friends who are also followers. Since the dataset has almost 2,000 ids, I’m positive this value is wrong.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?… I appreciate your guidance but, although there are many ways program these tasks, I do need to use the Sets and .intersection, so please try and help me using those only... =)

```
from twitter_login import oauth_login
from twitter_DB import load_from_DB
from sets import Set

def friends_and_followers(users):
    #open a lists for friends and another for followers
    friends_list, followers_list = [], []
    #find the users id under the label "friend_edges"   
    if id in users["friend_edges"] :
        #loop in the "friend edges" group and find id's values
        for value in id: 
            #add value to the list of friends
            friends_list += value   
        #put the rest of the ids under the followers' list
        else:
            followers_list += value            
    return friends_list, followers_list
    print friends_list, followers_list

    #convert list of friends into a set
    flist= set(friends_list)
    #convert list of friends into a set
    follwlist= set(followers_list)       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_api = oauth_login()
    # check couchdb to look at this database
    DBname = 'users-thatguy-+-only'
    # load all the tweets
    ff_results = load_from_DB(DBname)
    #show number loaded
    print 'number loaded', len(ff_results)


    #iterate over values in the file 
    for user_id in ff_results: 
        #run the function over the values        
        both_friends_followers = friends_and_followers(user_id)
    print "Friends and Followers of that guy:  ", len(both_friends_followers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get a length of two is because you return this:

```
return friends_list, followers_list
```

Which is a `tuple` of two `lists`, then take the length of that `tuple`, which is two.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convert from dictionary to set by extracting the values and adding those to a list using list.append(), as follows:

```
if 'friend_edges' in doc.keys(): 
        flist = []        
        for x in doc['friend_edges']:
            flist.append(x)
```